# Unable to download Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client from web launch

Tags: vpn

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 recently, which is the only OS on my pc. When try to download the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client from web launch windows executable file appears instead of Linux. Please help.

Looking for Similar file mentioned in this site 
https://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/how-do-i-install-cisco-anyconnect-client-linux

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install the openconnect client from the Ubuntu repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openconnect
```

Then you should be able to configure you VPN access from network-manager.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to  download only the 'cisco' Linux exutable file mentioned as example in this link..https://faq.oit.gatech.edu/content/how-do-i-install-cisco-anyconnect-client-linux

Comment: @Aditya Ok, I understand. I my experience, openconnect is perfectly compatible as a Cisco Anyconnect client. That said, if you really need / want the cisco "official" client you might want to look here http://software.cisco.com/download/release.html?mdfid=283000185&softwareid=282364313&release=3.0.08057